# Collapsing multiple columns containing the same variable into one column

Tags: r, reshape

My data looks like the following:

```
ID   Diagnosis_1   Diagnosis_2   Diagnosis_3   Diagnosis_4
A        1             0             0             0
A        1             0             0             0
A        1             0             0             0
B        0             1             0             0
C        0             0             0             1
C        0             1             0             0
D        0             0             0             1
E        0             0             1             0
E        0             1             0             0
E        0             0             1             0
```

Diagnosis_1:Diagnosis_4 are all binary, representing presence (1) or absence (0) of the diagnosis. What I'd like to do is create a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID   Diagnosis
A        1
A        1
A        1
B        2
C        4
C        2
D        4
E        3
E        2
E        3
```

No matter how many times I read the documentation on reshape/reshape2/tidyr I just can't manage to wrap my head around their implementation.

I can solve my problem using dplyr's mutate but it's a time-intensive, roundabout way to achieve my goal.

EDIT: Data edited to more realistically represent my actual data frame.

Answer (score 6):

Try matrix multiplication:

```
nc <- ncol(DF)
data.frame(ID = DF$ID, Diagnosis = as.matrix(DF[-1]) %*% seq(nc-1))
```

giving:

```
  ID Diagnosis
1  A         1
2  B         2
3  C         2
4  D         4
5  E         3
```

**Note:** We used this as input:

```
Lines <- "ID   Diagnosis_1   Diagnosis_2   Diagnosis_3   Diagnosis_4
A        1             0             0             0
B        0             1             0             0
C        0             1             0             0
D        0             0             0             1
E        0             0             1             0"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `max.col` to get the column indices for each row.

```
 data.frame(ID=df1$ID, Diagnosis=max.col(df1[-1]))
 #    ID Diagnosis
 #1  A         1
 #2  B         2
 #3  C         2
 #4  D         4
 #5  E         3
```

Or another option to get the index is

```
 unname(which(t(df1[-1])!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])
 #[1] 1 2 2 4 3
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(25)
 m1 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 1e8*5, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9, 0.1)), ncol=5)
 m2 <- m1[rowSums(m1)==1,]
 dim(m2)
 #[1] 32812201        5
 set.seed(395)
 df1 <- data.frame(ID= sample(LETTERS, nrow(m2), replace=TRUE), m2,
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
 colnames(df1)[-1] <- paste('X', 1:5, sep="_")

 Grothendieck <- function() {nc <- ncol(df1)
             data.frame(ID = df1$ID, Diagnosis =
                       as.matrix(df1[-1]) %*% seq(nc-1))}

akrun <- function() {data.frame(ID=df1$ID,
                   Diagnosis=max.col(df1[-1], 'first'))}
ananda <- function() {df1 %>%
                 gather(var, val, -ID) %>%
                 separate(var, into = c("var", "value")) %>%
                 filter(val == 1) %>%
                 select(ID, value)}

 system.time(akrun())
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 3.690   0.396   4.085 
 system.time(Grothendieck())
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 3.121   0.459   3.581
```

Tried `dplyr` solution on a smaller subset of 'df1' ie. 1e6 rows

```
df1 <- df1[1:1e6,]
system.time(ananda())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  6.279   0.177   6.454
```

Using `microbenchmark`,

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun(), Grothendieck(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq       max neval cld
 #      akrun() 1.019108 1.252443 1.084306 1.180743 1.16463 0.6928535    20  a
#Grothendieck() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000 1.0000000    20  a
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
 Diagnosis_1 = c(1L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Diagnosis_2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
 Diagnosis_3 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Diagnosis_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)),
 .Names = c("ID", 
 "Diagnosis_1", "Diagnosis_2", "Diagnosis_3", "Diagnosis_4"),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention "reshape2", "tidyr", and related tools, here are some options to consider:

```
## Using "tidyr" and "dplyr"
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  gather(var, val, -ID) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("var", "value")) %>%
  filter(val == 1) %>%
  select(ID, value)
#   ID value
# 1  A     1
# 2  B     2
# 3  C     2
# 4  E     3
# 5  D     4

## Getting half-way there with "melt" from "reshape2"
library(reshape2)
melt(replace(df1, df1 == 0, NA), id.vars = "ID", na.rm = TRUE)
#    ID    variable value
# 1   A Diagnosis_1     1
# 7   B Diagnosis_2     1
# 8   C Diagnosis_2     1
# 15  E Diagnosis_3     1
# 19  D Diagnosis_4     1
```

---

Considering your update, you just need to add a secondary ID:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = row_number()) %>%
  gather(var, val, Diagnosis_1:Diagnosis_4) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("var", "value")) %>%
  filter(val == 1) %>%
  arrange(ID, ID2)
# Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
# 
#    ID ID2       var value val
# 1   A   1 Diagnosis     1   1
# 2   A   2 Diagnosis     1   1
# 3   A   3 Diagnosis     1   1
# 4   B   1 Diagnosis     2   1
# 5   C   1 Diagnosis     4   1
# 6   C   2 Diagnosis     2   1
# 7   D   1 Diagnosis     4   1
# 8   E   1 Diagnosis     3   1
# 9   E   2 Diagnosis     2   1
# 10  E   3 Diagnosis     3   1
```

Comment: What are 'var' and 'val' referring to?

Comment: @MakairaMurakami, Those are the two columns you would be creating when the columns have been gathered.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error when I run the set of tidyr/dplyr commands: "Error: Values not split into 2 pieces at" which then goes on to list a long series of numbers.

Comment: @MakairaMurakami, do you have more columns/differently named columns than those in the sample you shared?

Comment: Yes, I have 5 diagnosis columns named "Diagnosis___1" through "Diagnosis__4" then "Diagnosis__10" along with the ID column.  Why does this make a difference given the code you provided?

Comment: @MakairaMurakami, with differing numbers of underscores like you show in the previous comment?

Comment: No, the same number of underscores. That was an error on my part.

Comment: @MakairaMurakami, can you edit your question to include the output of `head(yourdf, 10)` to share the first 10 rows, as read by R? That would help with troubleshooting.

Comment: @AnandoMahto I think I might know where the problem lies. My original data frame didn't represent the fact that my actual data lists some IDs multiple times (they're separate events). I've gone back and edited them to better reflect my real data.